# Apache2 permissions in /var/www/ multiple websites

Tags: permissions, apache2, chmod

I am working on a desktop environment with Ubuntu 18.04.

I have my Apache 2 server setup with multiple websites in the folder `/var/www/` (each site lives in its own folder there)

Made myself owner and assigned www-data as group : `sudo chown $USER:www-data -R /var/www`

Fixed permissions with : `sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www`

Everything works fine, untill I add a file or add a new website (git pull). New files will not come with the group www-data. Disallowing Apache to run.

This is fixed by re executing `sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www`, but this doesn't feel like a fix.

What do I do wrong?

Edit: It seems `git pull` doesn't respect the permissions I have set earlier. Even though the parent folder has the permissions set correctly.

Comment: Google "setgid bit".

Comment: @fkraiem Would you mind explaining a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set setgid bit for all folders:

```
chown $USER:www-data -R /var/www    
chmod -R g+s /var/www
```

Then every new file created in "setgid folder" will have group of parent folder. User who do create file must be in www-data group

WWW files permissions can be limited to your user(read-write) and www-data group(only read), while others don't have any persissions:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rs,o= /var/www
```

Comment: Will this mean I can't create files anymore under my own user? (without being in the group www-data)

Comment: Just add your user to `www-data`, and create any file will be fine. Created files will have incorrect group if user not in group.